# How do I solve this Partial Fractions question?

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

$$\frac{x^4}{(x^2-3)(x^2+3)}\;$$

How would I do this?

My attempt started with this:

$$\frac{A+Bx}{(x^2-3)}\; + \frac{C+Dx}{(x^2+3)}$$

But when I start working it all out, A, B, C and D all go to 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sign error. $B+D = 0$, but $3(B-D) = 1$, so $B$ and $D$ are not $0$.

Comment: check your calculations. I'm getting A,C=0 and B=1/6,D=-1/6

Comment: @danielfischer, Whoops, I accidentally forgot that there's an x^4 on the numerator

Comment: @VijayRaghavan, I accidentally forgot that there's an x^4 on the numerator

Comment: In that case, use $x^4 = (x^4 - 9) + 9$ to get $$1 + \frac{9}{(x^2-3)(x^2+3)}.$$ For a partial fraction decomposition, the degree of the numerator must be smaller than the degree of the denominator.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I'm confused to what happens after you make x^2 = (X^4 - 9)+9

Comment: $$\frac{x^4}{(x^2-3)(x^2+3)} = \frac{(x^4-9)+9}{(x^2-3)(x^2+3)} = 1 + \frac{9}{(x^2-3)(x^2+3)}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer, nope, I figured it out! Sweet, now it's good!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that the $x$ in the numerator is really supposed to be $x^4$, we first need the degree in the numerator to be less than that of the denominator before employing partial fraction decomposition. Note that the denominator can be expressed as the difference of squares: $x^4 - 9$, which makes polynomial division very straightforward. We can also see the factor $x^2 - 3$ as a difference of squares and factor accordingly knowing $x^2 - 3 = (x + \sqrt 3)(x - \sqrt 3)$:

$$\begin{align} \frac{x^4}{(x^2-3)(x^2+3)} & = \dfrac{(x^4 - 9) + 9}{(x^2 - 3)(x^2 + 3)} \\ \\\dfrac {x^4 - 9}{x^4 - 9} + \dfrac 9{(x^2 - 3)(x^2 + 3)} &= 1 + \dfrac 9{(x+ \sqrt 3)(x - \sqrt 3)(x^2 + 3)} \\ \\ &= 1 + \dfrac A{x + \sqrt 3} + \frac B{x - \sqrt 3} + \frac{Cx + D}{x^2 + 3}\end{align}$$

Comment: @Amzoti Ticked!

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$x^2-3=(x-\sqrt3)(x+\sqrt3)\implies$$

$$\frac x{(x-\sqrt3)(x+\sqrt3)(x^2+3)}=\frac A{x-\sqrt3}+\frac B{x+\sqrt3}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+3}$$